# Dependency 'com.amazonaws' not found

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create a spring boot aplication with **DynamoDB** database, following this **[tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-dynamodb)**.
After adding the project dependencies, it seems that maven can't find the **`com.amazonaws`** dependency, and that is causing a lot of errors in amazon variables, like `@EnableDynamoDBRepositories` for example.

This is the actual code of:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>crudynamo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crudynamo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
             <version>Lovelace-SR16</version>
             <type>pom</type>
             <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
             <version>5.1.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
             <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
             <version>1.11.166</version>
             <type>pom</type>
             <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

 </project>
```

**aplication.properties**

```
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=http://localhost:8000/
amazon.aws.accesskey=key
amazon.aws.secretkey=key2
```

**DynamoDBConfig.java**

```
package com.example.crudynamo;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

 @Configuration
 @EnableDynamoDBRepositories //error
         (basePackages = "com.baeldung.spring.data.dynamodb.repositories")
 public class DynamoDBConfig {

     @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
     private String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint;

     @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
     private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

     @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
     private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

     //error in AmazonDynamoDB

     @Bean
     public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
         AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB
                 = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(amazonAWSCredentials());

         if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint)) {
             amazonDynamoDB.setEndpoint(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint);
         }

         return amazonDynamoDB;
     }

     @Bean
     public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials() {
         return new BasicAWSCredentials(
                 amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey);
     }
 }
```

I've searched in other similar questions like that, but none of them solved this problem.

Comment: You have 2 sections of `dependencies`. Have you tried combining them?

Comment: You're right, I've combined them now, but the error still persists.

Comment: Now it doesn't seem like you're pulling in any AWS dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **pom.xml** file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>crudynamo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crudynamo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Lovelace-SR16</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- new dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- this dependency is now inside 'dependencies' tag -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.774</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

You were forgetting to add the `com.github.derjust`dependency. For some reason too, I was getting this error when `com.amazonaws` was inside the `dependencyManagement` tag. Moving him to the `dependencies` tag did the work.

After this, you'll be able to import amazon variables in your **DynamoDBConfig.java** file with the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for every variable.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @IncredibleCoding actually the same I told you yesterday already (s. my answer)

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the dependency

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

into dependencies of your pom, now you have it only in dependencyManagement, but that's not enough. And then include following imports in your `DynamoDBConfig.java` file:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials; 
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials; 
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB; 
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient; 
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.config.EnableDynamoDBRepositories;
```

Comment: I forgot to put this dependency, but it still doesn't work :/